Deployment error of Fiori App (RAP - OData V2) from BAS
I have created two projects in Eclipse (in 2 different packages) and created a fiori app in BAS for each one of them. For both of them I added the Excel Upload button. Deployed it the first one successfully but now when I try to deploy the second one I get this error:
Duplicate Id: Id cc.spreadsheetimporter.v0_32_0 already contained in SAPUI5 Repository ZZZZZZZZ_V2
The first one is deployed and released from Eclipse as the first image
enter image description here
and the second one as TR :
enter image description here
I tried to modify the version of my spreadsheetimporter to 0.33.3 but is not working.
